# In pycharm how to change unit test to pytest in this dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, pytest

When I open a new Python file, this small dialog gives the option to make a unit test template as is in the picture. I want to change this shortcut to instead create a `pytest` one.
How can i do that?

And, can I put more "templates/shortcuts" in this dialog? That will save time on some templates that I use a lot to start new projects.

[image: The new py file options dialog]

I already installed pytest, and went through this:

> Open the Settings/Preferences | Tools | Python Integrated Tools settings dialog as described in Choosing Your Testing Framework.
>
> In the Default test runner field select pytest.

But even with pytest as default, the dialog still shows "unit test" only and not pytest.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want as a pytest template - as there is no class and no import that is needed, you can just use the template for a Python file (or no template at all, as it will be an empty file). As for the default testing tool - this is used for _running_ a test, not for creating a test file.

Comment: i mean, that small portion of code that it writes automatically, like it makes with unit test. this is the model that i would use https://repl.it/@leobel/DojoPythonBase-1 (code on the main.py). this link is a model that i leave on repl and, everytime i want to use it, i can just fork it and start from there, i want to do it in pycharm but in this dialog, to have right from there and it will be very fast like just click ing on pytest in that box and start with that , its less setup time for a code that i use a lot

Comment: You mean the `main.py` there? That does not make much sense as a pytest template in my opinion - but if you want it, you can just add your own file template under Settings | Editor | File and Code templates.

Comment: yes , the main , i edited to be more clear (passed the time to edit, so i deleted and posted the edited one now) . that's  a code that our group made to start the "coding dojo"s sessions which in that we use pytest. i'm quite a newbie. so, can you explain why don't make sense and how could be better ?

Comment: Ah ok, so it's for helping to learn pytest - it would not make sense for me because a usual pytest file does not import anything pytest related, except you use something like `parametrize`. Anyway, as I wrote, you can configure a new template type, and just select that under "New...".

Comment: i just added to the templates, it worked and for this case its even better because it appears on the first menu before the smaller one. you could put that tip in a answer here. i will wait if somebody show how to add to the smaller menu too beacuse now that i know that way, i foreseen the templates in the first menu will become too full with time. so putting in the smaller one will be more organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the selection menu for the Python file type that you get if you select `New...|Python file` is not configurable. You can, however, add a file template yourself, that will appear in the list of file types you get if you select `New...`.
The easiest way to access this is via `New...|Edit File Templates...`, or you can get to the same dialog via `Settings...|Editor|File and Code Templates`. You can add templates for all new projects (schema `Default`), or for the current project only (schema `Project`), though that makes sense only for large projects.

Note that your custom file templates are always ordered alphabetically in the list, so if you want to show them in a specific order, you may use some prefix in the template names to enforce the wanted order.

*Note*:
I checked in PyCharm code where the internal file templates (e.g. the templates in the "New Python file" dialog) are handled, and this seems indeed to be hardcoded. Short of adapting the PyCharm code there seems to be no possibility to configure this.